# Is it possible to sandbox and run C++ or C# code that's entered in a textfield in a browser?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm diving into web development after ten years of desktop development and I'm experimenting with some testing concepts.  I was wondering if it's possible to sandbox and run C++ code that's entered in a textfield in a browser?  By that, I mean run the C++ or C# code on the backend webserver and return an analysis of the code.  Just to be clear, I don't mean run C++ or C# code that's intended to generate any kind of markup, but simply to blackbox test the C++ or C# block of code that's entered.

1. How would you invoke the compiler, depending on the web server you're using?
2. How could you sandbox the code to prevent malicious behavior?  If we're considering only one of the C variants, what about blacklisting/whitelisting specific functions and libraries to prevent malicious behavior?  Or would that blacklist be too long and too limiting to allow any fair amount of code to run?

These are some fairly high-level questions that I'm asking just because I'm having a hard time finding some direction, but I'm going to continue researching them right now.  Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: their would be a way of doing this... but I am more stuck on why you would want to do this...

Comment: @thecoshman, for similar reasons to why the codepad website (see responses below) exists, just to share code and their runtime results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find [the codepad about page](http://codepad.org/about) interesting.

Comment: think you need to fix this one :P EDIT: nearly their :D FINAL EDIT: YAY! Link

Answer (score 3):

# 1 is easy with C#. The Reflection capabilities of .NET allow you to [compile and run code "on the fly."](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm) And here's a link to [another good looking tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/reflection/article.php/c5881).

# 2 is a little more difficult but I suppose a basic sand boxing technique might involve executing a dynamic process under a limited, and therefore sand boxed account. Programmatically you could analyze the dynamicly built assembly's dependencies and not allow it to run if it used APIs in certain namespaces such as System.IO. This is non-trivial to say the least though.

C++ doesn't have reflection capabilities and so 3rd party libraries would be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, that looks like a great capability to explore!

Answer (score 2):

The [Dinkumware site](http://www.dinkumware.com/exam/default.aspx) has something like this.

A simple Perl (or Python, ...) cgi could be used to invoke the compiler, parse it results, run the resulting executable if any and display it's results.

I would take a look at SELinux (maybe AppArmor?) for access controls. Maybe not allowing it write and read to/from the disk and limit it's running time. I don't know if the later can be done with SELinux, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the server runs Linux, you may consider using [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)

Comment: YOu need root access for that, and chroot merely changes your root. (Hence the name), it is NOT a sandbox, and was never designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

We actually did just that with our product called iKnode. We are using this idea to create a Backend in the cloud.

We did this by creating a SandBox that takes an specific piece of code and executes it, captures the result and returns it to the user. This is all done in the cloud.

> How would you invoke the compiler, depending on the web server you're
>   using?

We did this by using the CodeDom utilities from the .Net framework. And we are exploring the coming 'compiler as a service' project coming from Microsoft code-named Roslyn.

This is a good starting point on using [CodeDom](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655) to programatically compile.

> How could you sandbox the code to prevent malicious behavior? If we're
>   considering only one of the C variants, what about
>   blacklisting/whitelisting specific functions and libraries to prevent
>   malicious behavior? Or would that blacklist be too long and too
>   limiting to allow any fair amount of code to run?

We did this by wrapping the code execution in a separate and limited AppDomain. You can see some examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0240__Assembly/0020__AppDomain.htm).

Additionally, you might want to look into the MonoSandBox, which was created for Moonlight, but it is a more robust SandBox. We are experimenting with it right now, to move away from AppDomains. We believe the MonoSandBox is way better than simple AppDomains.